# Excel - show numbers that don't appear to two columns

Tags: excel

I have two columns of data:

```
Col1         Col2
234          234
334          334
543          543
667          100
100          222
222
900
```

What I would like to achieve is to have Excel return the numbers that don't appear in both columns.  So the result would be:

```
667
900
```

Thanks in advance for any advice and assistance.

Comment: I think that VLOOKUP might help.  You can get a true/false off a range, and show a result.

Comment: Thanks, just reading up on that, hadn't spotted it before asking the question!

Comment: NP.  It's one that people tend to not know about.  But it has it's uses.

Comment: In your example, both values to be returned are present in the larger of the two columns, though not in the smaller. Is it also possible that the converse can occur, i.e. that one or more values from the smaller column are not present in the larger?

Comment: @XORLX - good question, but in this instance, no - it's the second column that has the number missing from the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using MATCH will tell you if a value is in the range specified, applying the ISNA method (is not a number) will identify the non-matches - so the following copied over seven rows will throw out the missing numbers:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A1,B$1:B$5,0)),A1,"")
```

[image: isna and match]

Comment: Thanks for this, again, I've just compared your response to the `VLOOKUP' and the 'MATCH' @pnuts provided.  Yours provides the actual missing number, which is a nice touch - thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You might try:

```
=MATCH(A2,B$2:B$6,0)
```

and

```
=MATCH(B2,A$2:A$8,0)
```

both copied down, where `#N/A` should indicate the rows in which the values do not match (for each column).

Comment: I just compared the results of the `VLOOKUP' and the 'MATCH' you have kindly provided above - they both provide the same results.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for @durbnpoisn

A `VLOOKUP` in Excel allows to do exactly this: http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx

**Syntax**
VLOOKUP(lookup_value,table_array,col_index_num,range_lookup)

*Lookup_value*    The value to search in the first column of the table array. Lookup_value can be a value or a reference. If lookup_value is smaller than the smallest value in the first column of table_array, VLOOKUP returns the #N/A error value.

*Table_array*    Two or more columns of data. Use a reference to a range or a range name. The values in the first column of table_array are the values searched by lookup_value. These values can be text, numbers, or logical values. Uppercase and lowercase text are equivalent.

*Col_index_num*    The column number in table_array from which the matching value must be returned. A col_index_num of 1 returns the value in the first column in table_array; a col_index_num of 2 returns the value in the second column in table_array, and so on. If col_index_num is:

Less than 1, VLOOKUP returns the #VALUE! error value.
Greater than the number of columns in table_array, VLOOKUP returns the #REF! error value.
Range_lookup    A logical value that specifies whether you want VLOOKUP to find an exact match or an approximate match:

If TRUE or omitted, an exact or approximate match is returned. If an exact match is not found, the next largest value that is less than lookup_value is returned.
The values in the first column of table_array must be placed in ascending sort order; otherwise, VLOOKUP may not give the correct value. You can put the values in ascending order by choosing the Sort command from the Data menu and selecting Ascending. For more information, see Default sort orders.

If FALSE, VLOOKUP will only find an exact match. In this case, the values in the first column of table_array do not need to be sorted. If there are two or more values in the first column of table_array that match the lookup_value, the first value found is used. If an exact match is not found, the error value #N/A is returned.

Answer (score 0):

a conditional statement could do this

Probably another solution

```
=IF(A1=A2,"",A1)
```

might be helpful